# How to encode the JWT decode token payload on client-side in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jwt, angular8

I'm using angular2-jwt to resolve the code after http.get.
I need to encode the body while sending http post.

```
let body = {
 "sub": "1234567890",
 "name": "John Doe",
 "iat": 1516239022
};

this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers }).subscribe(res => {
       resolve(res);
     }, (err) => {
       resolve(err);
});
```

Comment: why you have to do that? once you logged in server should send you the encoded jwt token in header.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do by using `resolve` here?  your `res` will contains the data you received

```
this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers }).subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res)//here res is your body/data
     }, (err) => {
       resolve(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't encode it, you encode JWT with the secret key, which is something you should never expose to the client.

To decode the JWT you would have had to had the original encoded JWT floating around already, send that back to the server instead of the decoded object.